# owl-Carousel 2 se carga varias veces y despues se hacce lento la carga de datos en el slider

Tags: angularjs

estoy trabajando una app con angular, estoy utilizando owl-carousel y estoy utilizando la directiva de owlcarousel que permite inicializar el slider una vez se halla cargado el ultimo dato con ng-repeat.

```js
app.directive("owlCarousel", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.initCarousel = function(element) {
                   **console.log(element);**
                // provide any default options you want
                var defaultOptions = {
                };
                var customOptions = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));
                // combine the two options objects
                for(var key in customOptions) {
                    defaultOptions[key] = customOptions[key];
                }
                // init carousel
                $(element).owlCarousel(defaultOptions);
            };

         // Let lissen for events.
        }
    };
});


app.directive('owlCarouselItem', [function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: false,
    link: function(scope, element) {
      // wait for the last item in the ng-repeat then call init
        if(scope.$last) {
            scope.initCarousel(element.parent());
        }
    }
};
}]);
```

he colocado en negro la salida en la consola para que puedan entenderme. en la ventana de dialogo tengo especificado un template para cargar el slider, una vez cargada la informacion, el console.log sale indefinido, pero despues de tres click que hago para que despliegue el slider dentro del md-dialog, salen 3 lineas en el console.log del element y asi sucesivamente hasta cargarse mas 30 veces y no encuentro la manera de resetar o hacer que el owlcarousel que esta dentro de esta directiva inicie como nuevo cada vez que inicio la ventana de dialogo. porque cada vez que acceso a el va consumiendo como memoria y se hace mas lenta la carga.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**asi llamo al slider**

```
$mdDialog.show({
  controller: SliderController,
  scope: $scope,
  preserveScope: true,
  //templateUrl: 'Slider.tmpl.html',
  template: "<md-dialog-content id="contenido" ng-style="{'height': iframeHeight + 'px','max-height': iframeHeight + 'px',  'max-width': iframeWidth + 'px', 'width': iframeWidth + 'px'}">
        <owl-carousel id='owl-product-catalog' class="owl-carousel owl-theme" data-options="{items:1, dots:false, center:true, loop:false, margin:0, singleItem:true, navigation:true}">
            <div owl-carousel-item="catalogoid"  ng-repeat="catalogoid in todoelcatalogo" ng-cloak>
              <img ng-image-appear ng-pinch-zoom ng-style="{height: iframeHeight + 'px', 'max-height': iframeHeight + 'px', 'max-width': iframeWidth + 'px', width: iframeWidth + 'px'}" ng-src='{{catalogoid.file}}' />
            </div>
        </owl-carousel>
</md-dialog-content>'",
  parent: angular.element(document.body),
  targetEvent: ev,
  clickOutsideToClose:true,
  bindToController:true,
  fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen,
      locals: {var1: data, var2: dataimg} })
  .then(function(answer) {
  $scope.status = 'Aceptado';
}, function() {
  $scope.status = 'Cancelado';
});
};
```

**y este es parte del codigo del temaplte**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<md-dialog-content id="contenido" ng-style="{'height': iframeHeight + 'px','max-height': iframeHeight + 'px',  'max-width': iframeWidth + 'px', 'width': iframeWidth + 'px'}">
            <owl-carousel id='owl-product-catalog' class="owl-carousel owl-theme" data-options="{items:1, dots:false, center:true, loop:false, margin:0, singleItem:true, navigation:true}">
                <div owl-carousel-item="catalogoid"  ng-repeat="catalogoid in todoelcatalogo" ng-cloak>
                  <img ng-image-appear ng-pinch-zoom ng-style="{height: iframeHeight + 'px', 'max-height': iframeHeight + 'px', 'max-width': iframeWidth + 'px', width: iframeWidth + 'px'}" ng-src="{{catalogoid.file}}" />
                </div>
            </owl-carousel>
</md-dialog-content>
```

quiero pedir disculpas a alejandro y toda la comunidad, es que no me explique quien sabe de la mejor manera, pero en realidad lo que quiero saber es como poder remover el plugin owl-carousel despues de usarlo o que el mddialog se haya destruido. aqui va un ejemplo de que sucede, cuando cargo el $mddialog, se activa el plugin OWL. este cuando hago debug lo puedo ver inicializado asi:

```
**jQuery.fn.init [owl-carousel, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
   0:owl-carousel
   length:1
   prevObject:jQuery.fn.init [document]
   __proto__:Object(0)**
```

ok ahora envio un evento destroy y algunas otras funciones para ir destruyendolo y hago esto:

```
    **$('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel').destroy();
    $('.owl-stage-outer').remove();
    $('.md-dialog-container').remove();
    owl.html(owl.find('.owl-stage-outer').html()).removeClass('owl-loaded');
    owl.html(owl.find('.owl-stage-outer').html()).removeClass('owl-drag');
    owl.html(owl.find('.owl-stage-outer').html()).removeClass('owl-theme');
    owl.html(owl.find('.owl-stage-outer').html()).removeClass('owl-carousel');
    owl.html(owl.find('.owl-stage-outer').html()).removeClass('owl-carousel');
    owl.find('.owl-stage-outer').children().unwrap();
    owl.wrapAll('owl-carousel');
    owl.wrapAll('.__proto__');
    owl.remove();**
```

Pero mi sorpresa es que la funcion init del jquery del OWL no puedo removerlo ni eliminarlo de la memoria y entonces me queda asi:

```
**jQuery.fn.init {}
    __proto__: Object(0)**
```

Ahora si va mi pregunta: Como destruyo "jQuery.fn.init {}"
he intentado varias opciones delete, remove, wrapAll pero no lo eliminan apunto a **owl.fn.init.remove()** y nada.

Creo que de esta manera es mas facil que me entiendan y puedan ayudarme.

Comment: está fallando el snippet!!

Comment: como pudiera hacer para que puedas ver el proyecto correr y te des cuenta de lo que te explico ya viendolo ejecutandose creo que sabras lo que digo...

Comment: he cambiado el código. Echa un ojo a la opción template, así es como se anidan las plantillas sin un HTML asociado. añade angularJS al snippet, y en nada lo mejoramos y lo tendremos completo para probar

Comment: he editado la pregunta al final para explicarme mejor. Gracias Alejandro.

Comment: Tranqui! luego intento encender el pc q no lo tengo ahora y miro si puedo ayudarte!!

Comment: Oye hoy seguro que puedo echarte una mano. Avísame por aquí cuando andes conectado y tratamos de abrir un chat !!

Comment: ya estoy aca,... avisame