# como remuevo de la memoria owl-carousel y no morir en el intento

Tags: angularjs, owl

Hola estoy me he desarrollado una App en la que uso owl-carousel que lo llamo dentro de un md-dialog en angularjs.

El problema es que cada vez que la llamo se carga el owl-carousel muchas veces ocupando mucho espacio en memoria y no logro poder hacer un destroy del plugins.

utilizo la directiva de owl-carousel.

```
offerapp.directive("owlCarousel", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: false,
    link: function (scope) {

        scope.initCarousel = function(element) {
            console.log(element);
          // provide any default options you want
            var defaultOptions = {
            };
            var customOptions = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));
            // combine the two options objects
            for(var key in customOptions) {
                defaultOptions[key] = customOptions[key];
            }
            // init carousel
            $(element).owlCarousel(defaultOptions);
        };

        // Let lissen for events.
    }
};
});

offerapp.directive('owlCarouselItem', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: false,
        link: function(scope, element) {
          // wait for the last item in the ng-repeat then call init
            if(scope.$last) {  
                //console.log($(element).data('owlCarousel'));
                scope.initCarousel(element.parent());
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

he puesto un console.log(element) y ahí fue que me di cuenta que se cargaba múltiple veces sin destruirse.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Oye, viendo eso, puede ser que tengas un controlador anidado alrededor de esa directiva..? Es decir, ng-controller declarado dentro del HTML y que envuelva al dialog?????? En ese caso, si tienes un controller dentro de un ng-repeat, etc.. se cargará varias veces... puede tener que ver?? Puedes pegar el HTML de ese pedazo para dejarlo perfecto?

Comment: Y ahora que lo pienso, compruebas si es el último...  if(scope.$last), por lo que debería no funcionar a menos que sea lo del controller... creo. Te diría que es un problema de que tienes el ng-controller anidado dentro del ng-repeat, y entonces cargas la funcionalidad N veces (Donde N será igual que el número del ng-repeat), pero todas para el último

Comment: hola Alejandro gracias por tomarte tu tiempo y ayudarme. mira yo cargo en el index body esto:

<body ng-class="{isOpen : isOpen}" ng-app="Panamacity" ng-controller="PrincipalController" id="mainController" class="ng-cloak">
        <div ng-view autoscroll></div>

Comment: el template que carga el $mddialog usa una funcion como controller.

Comment: puedes verlo mas claro aqui:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/132884/owl-carousel-2-se-carga-varias-veces-y-despues-se-hacce-lento-la-carga-de-datos

Comment: Claro, pero el tema es que esa funcion que tienesd como ng-controller, se va a cargar N veces, tantas como opciones tengas en el NG-REPEAT. Es decir, si has anidado el controlador poniéndolo como ng-controller, sí que se anida esto.  Echa un ojo a esta respuesta que dí en su día sobre este problema: 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280548/3617531

Comment: has duplicado la pregunta?? puedes editarla!

Comment: ya veo lo que me dices, pero como puedo enseñarte el html del template que usa el mddialog para que veas que dentro de ese template no uso ng-controller. o es recomendable que utilice en el encabezado del template un div con ngcontroller ???? y asi de esa forma cuando e destrulla el $mddialog tambien se destruye el Owl-carrousel ????